# visual basic 6- how to connect vb6 with oracle 10g in 64 bit processor

Tags: vb6

I am doing a project using visual basic 6 as front  end and oracle 10 g as back end. 
Our project successfully runs in 32 bit processor,but fails to get connected in 64 bit processor.
Any one help me out of this problem.
Is there any method ??

Comment: maybe you could give us some details...

Comment: Fails how? A 32 bit exe using 32 bit drivers should work fine on a 64 bit version of windows.

Comment: @Rob  i got connection error when i tried to connect oracle and vb6 in 64 bit processor. connection i used was :ADODB... note:Visual Basic 6 and oracle 10 g

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use 32-bit version of ODBC on 64-bit Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713308/use-32-bit-version-of-odbc-on-64-bit-windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Use the 32-bit ODBC manager to add your DSN:
The manager is located in:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

that should be able to see the 32-bit ODBC driver, add a DNS in the manager and use the same when connecting to DB.

Once you done with this, you can repeat the way you connected your DB to VB6 as you done with 32 bit Windows 7.

If you still getting problems, let me know =)

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon and often [get deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) or converted to comments. Please include all essential information in the answer itself. Alternatively, just leave a comment with the link.

Comment: I was going to comment, but that need some 50 points, I don't have that yet

Comment: Apart from the link, the problems really had taken much time than I had thought to complete a mini-project

Comment: Our universities still have VB and Oracle based simple mini project in Engineering syllabus

Comment: So I copied the solution which helped resolve me the same problem she is getting

Comment: @dragonknight thank you. it would be helpful. i can have a try as you said